# Relationship between variables in a proposed model using linear regression?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, multicollinearity, polynomial

I am new to linear regression and I am currently working on a linear regression problem - I have 8 features and one output.

The features I am using seem unrelated to each other and I found an article (https://datatofish.com/multiple-linear-regression-python/) which suggests to check if there is a relationship between the variables. This brings me to my first question - When starting off with a (multiple) linear regression problem, How do we evaluate the problem is suitable for linear regression? Do we always need to check if there is a linear relationship between the output and each of the input features? It seems quite tedious if we will have more than 10 features to do this.

And if there is no linear relationship between the output and the features used to predict it, I suppose the next course of action to try polynomial regression.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first thing I usually prefer is to look at the data - e.g. scatter plot of each regressor with y variable. That can help to understand if any transformation is required on any x variable or not, and also will help getting a sense of the data to work with.
Secondly, residual diagnostics is very important aspect to understand whether the model makes sense or not - e.g. scatterplot of residual vs. prediction. There are a number of different diagnostics which can be done post building the model on the basis of some assumption, and validate.

Comment: Yes, visualizing the data makes it clearer. What do you mean by transformation on the x variable? Do you mean normalization and if yes, how would it help?

Comment: x and y not necessarily be linearly related, there may exist some non-linear relationship which can still be modelled through regression - like you yourself mentioned polynomial regression. It may make sense to apply log transformation, or any power transformation on a variable - these can be figured out by visualizing the data, or by running some diagnostic tests on the residual series. Also, you should ideally have some belief/ prior knowledge on how strong the x variable should be driving your y variable - to make a sensible choice of variables in a model.

Answer (score 0):

The most important assumption in linear regression is features should have linear and additive relationship with the target variable. You can use pearson correlation to find the strength/direction of relationship among the variables or you can analyse the relationship visually through scatterplots.

If there is no linear relationship then you should try to use tree based or other non-linear methods which captures the non-linear interactions effectively.

Comment: Thank you! My variables have very little correlation with each other, I get a value of about 0.09 and such, I suppose I will have to try non-linear methods.